# Keep-Alive in Headers

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers, page-speed

On my server we have mod_headers.c enabled.

I'm using the below code to enable Keep-Alive

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
```

Is there any reason why GTMetrix or some other sites doesn't pick this up?

Been scratching my head for a while on this now.

Answer (score 2):

**Enabling Keep-Alive**

Ensure in Apache you have set ( from [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/enable-keep-alive.html) )

```
KeepAlive On
```

Setting a header does not enable keep-alive.  You must also enable this in Apache.